# c# selenium form submission

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm having issues with if submit form is available then submit data and check for response, it seems to check for submit form, submit the data but then doesn't process the response given, example of code:

```
            if (driver.FindElements(By.Name("search")).Count > 0 && driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).Displayed)
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("search")).SendKeys(query + Keys.Enter);

                if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='not found']/h2")).Count > 0 && driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='not found']/h2")).Displayed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("search not found");
                    driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com");
                }

            }
```

what this should doing is:

if

```
driver.findelement(by.name("search")
```

is true, then

```
driver.findelement(by.name("search").sendkeys(query)
```

then, check for response provided and handle using given commands within the if statement.

Comment: and where do you check the response for result found? I expected to see something like `if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='results']")) { ... } else if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='not found']/h2")) { .... } else { ...}`

Comment: You should do `driver.FindElement(By.Name("search"))` only once and save the result.  You should check return value from `SendKeys(query + Keys.Enter);`, did it succeed?

Comment: Your code trials to _check for response_ please.

Comment: I would not save the result of `driver.FindElement(By.Name("search"))` into a variable, this can lead to [StaleElementReferenceException](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) when the page is updated or the DOM changes, the only safe way to do it is to use the [Page Object Model](https://www.swtestacademy.com/page-object-model-c/).

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite this a little to make it a little more readable and not hit the page so many times. Every time you do `driver.findElement()`, Selenium scrapes the page. Scrape it once, do all your analysis using that first scrape, and then proceed.

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> search = GetVisibleElements(By.Name("search"));
if (search.Any())
{
    search.ElementAt(0).SendKeys(query + Keys.Enter);

    if (GetVisibleElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='not found']/h2")).Any())
    {
        // search not found
        Console.WriteLine("search not found");
        Driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com");
    }
    else
    {
        // search found
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Since you are checking more than once if an element exists and is visible, I would wrap that code in a function to make it more usable and make your code easier to read.

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> GetVisibleElements(By locator)
{
    return Driver.FindElements(locator).Where(e => e.Displayed).ToList();
}
```

This function locates the elements based on the locator provided, filters it down to only those elements that are displayed, and then returns the list. You can then see if there are any elements in the returned list in your script.